# Is there a way of getting the stateRoot of the last block in a contract?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, uniswap, assembly, merkle-patricia-tries

So i was curious if you could write a contract, that retrieves the StateRoot from the last mined block. I found a Repo from Keydonix, who used the stateRoot from previous blocks to calculate a more recent price change for dexes.
The solidity file below was written by him, unfortunately, i know very little about assembly code. I can see that the contract stores more than 16 variables, which causes the error of "Stack too deep(31)".
In line 33, he comments that the variables could be compressed into a single add function to save gas. Could anyone help me with how i would go about writing that in assembly?
Also, seeing as its a library i was thinking on perhaps making another library to lower the burden of high variable count on a single contract but wasnt sure seeing as its assembly.

Repo:
https://github.com/Keydonix/uniswap-oracle/

Best regards
Mango

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;

library BlockVerifier {
    function extractStateRootAndTimestamp(bytes memory rlpBytes) internal view returns (bytes32 stateRoot, uint256 blockTimestamp, uint256 blockNumber) {
        assembly {
            function revertWithReason(message, length) {
                mstore(0, 0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
                mstore(4, 0x20)
                mstore(0x24, length)
                mstore(0x44, message)
                revert(0, add(0x44, length))
            }

            function readDynamic(prefixPointer) -> dataPointer, dataLength {
                let value := byte(0, mload(prefixPointer))
                switch lt(value, 0x80)
                case 1 {
                    dataPointer := prefixPointer
                    dataLength := 1
                }
                case 0 {
                    dataPointer := add(prefixPointer, 1)
                    dataLength := sub(value, 0x80)
                }
            }

            // get the length of the data
            let rlpLength := mload(rlpBytes)
            // move pointer forward, ahead of length
            rlpBytes := add(rlpBytes, 0x20)

            // we know the length of the block will be between 483 bytes and 709 bytes, which means it will have 2 length bytes after the prefix byte, so we can skip 3 bytes in
            // CONSIDER: we could save a trivial amount of gas by compressing most of this into a single add instruction
            let parentHashPrefixPointer := add(rlpBytes, 3)
            let parentHashPointer := add(parentHashPrefixPointer, 1)
            let uncleHashPrefixPointer := add(parentHashPointer, 32)
            let uncleHashPointer := add(uncleHashPrefixPointer, 1)
            let minerAddressPrefixPointer := add(uncleHashPointer, 32)
            let minerAddressPointer := add(minerAddressPrefixPointer, 1)
            let stateRootPrefixPointer := add(minerAddressPointer, 20)
            let stateRootPointer := add(stateRootPrefixPointer, 1)
            let transactionRootPrefixPointer := add(stateRootPointer, 32)
            let transactionRootPointer := add(transactionRootPrefixPointer, 1)
            let receiptsRootPrefixPointer := add(transactionRootPointer, 32)
            let receiptsRootPointer := add(receiptsRootPrefixPointer, 1)
            let logsBloomPrefixPointer := add(receiptsRootPointer, 32)
            let logsBloomPointer := add(logsBloomPrefixPointer, 3)
            let difficultyPrefixPointer := add(logsBloomPointer, 256)
            let difficultyPointer, difficultyLength := readDynamic(difficultyPrefixPointer)
            let blockNumberPrefixPointer := add(difficultyPointer, difficultyLength)
            let blockNumberPointer, blockNumberLength := readDynamic(blockNumberPrefixPointer)
            let gasLimitPrefixPointer := add(blockNumberPointer, blockNumberLength)
            let gasLimitPointer, gasLimitLength := readDynamic(gasLimitPrefixPointer)
            let gasUsedPrefixPointer := add(gasLimitPointer, gasLimitLength)
            let gasUsedPointer, gasUsedLength := readDynamic(gasUsedPrefixPointer)
            let timestampPrefixPointer := add(gasUsedPointer, gasUsedLength)
            let timestampPointer, timestampLength := readDynamic(timestampPrefixPointer)

            blockNumber := shr(sub(256, mul(blockNumberLength, 8)), mload(blockNumberPointer))
            let blockHash := blockhash(blockNumber)
            let rlpHash := keccak256(rlpBytes, rlpLength)
            if iszero(eq(blockHash, rlpHash)) { revertWithReason("blockHash != rlpHash", 20) }

            stateRoot := mload(stateRootPointer)
            blockTimestamp := shr(sub(256, mul(timestampLength, 8)), mload(timestampPointer))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Ethereum Smart Contract at the time being. Because there is no EVM opcode to retrieve that: [EVM opcode list](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/), and there is no precompiled contract to do that: [Ethereum precompiled contracts](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go). The closest information you can get to verify something is the `BLOCKHASH` opcode, but it alone is not enough for verification.

The contract(library) you found has the purpose to verify what is submitted in a transaction by oracle or some actors using information from JSON-RPC interface of an Ethereum node. The unavailability of `StateRoot` on EVM is also stated by the author of the `uniswap-oracle` code in [Medium post about Uniswap Oracle](https://medium.com/@epheph/using-uniswap-v2-oracle-with-storage-proofs-3530e699e1d3). Nonetheless, there may have EIPs to provide such `StateRoot` opcode in the future if they get approved.

Comment: I was getting confused about where exactly the "proof" was coming from. But, its as you say, the previous root had to be given by some exterior off-chain source. I sincerely thank you for taking your time and clearing that up!